# Why are there (almost) no current shunt probes?

Tags: current-measurement, oscilloscope, shunt, probe

Most of the current probes for osciloscopes I can find are somehow magnetically coupled and have a high isolation and price.
However, in PCB design shunt resistors are often used.

Why does one not just use a shunt for current measurement?
If "breaking" the circuit and adding the shunt in series is an option?

I found one example, the uCurrent from EEVBlog.
And I was wondering if one could use multiple current shunt amplifiers, like one of the TI INA series with high common mode voltage to build a multi channel current sensing board to interface with an oscilloscope.

I'm pretty sure there is a good reason I could not find anything like that.

Comment: If you want to measure current that way, you provide your own shunt, and then connect a differential voltage probe across it. There are plenty of those.

Comment: Shunt resistors are very often used to measure current in PCBs. They are designed in-situ right from the start and, a voltage probe is used. Think about ohms law.